# How to draw the plot of within-cluster sum-of-squares for a cluster?

Tags: r, plot, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have a cluster plot by R while I want to optimize the "elbow criterion" of clustering with a wss plot, but I do not know how to draw a wss plot for a giving cluster, anyone would help me?

Here is my data:

```
Friendly<-c(0.467,0.175,0.004,0.025,0.083,0.004,0.042,0.038,0,0.008,0.008,0.05,0.096)
Polite<-c(0.117,0.55,0,0,0.054,0.017,0.017,0.017,0,0.017,0.008,0.104,0.1)
Praising<-c(0.079,0.046,0.563,0.029,0.092,0.025,0.004,0.004,0.129,0,0,0,0.029)
Joking<-c(0.125,0.017,0.054,0.383,0.108,0.054,0.013,0.008,0.092,0.013,0.05,0.017,0.067)
Sincere<-c(0.092,0.088,0.025,0.008,0.383,0.133,0.017,0.004,0,0.063,0,0,0.188)
Serious<-c(0.033,0.021,0.054,0.013,0.2,0.358,0.017,0.004,0.025,0.004,0.142,0.021,0.108)
Hostile<-c(0.029,0.004,0,0,0.013,0.033,0.371,0.363,0.075,0.038,0.025,0.004,0.046)
Rude<-c(0,0.008,0,0.008,0.017,0.075,0.325,0.313,0.004,0.092,0.063,0.008,0.088)
Blaming<-c(0.013,0,0.088,0.038,0.046,0.046,0.029,0.038,0.646,0.029,0.004,0,0.025)
Insincere<-c(0.075,0.063,0,0.013,0.096,0.017,0.021,0,0.008,0.604,0.004,0,0.1)
Commanding<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0.233,0.046,0.029,0.004,0.004,0.538,0,0.146)
Suggesting<-c(0.038,0.15,0,0,0.083,0.058,0,0,0,0.017,0.079,0.133,0.442)
Neutral<-c(0.021,0.075,0.017,0,0.033,0.042,0.017,0,0.033,0.017,0.021,0.008,0.717)

data <- data.frame(Friendly,Polite,Praising,Joking,Sincere,Serious,Hostile,Rude,Blaming,Insincere,Commanding,Suggesting,Neutral)
```

And here is my code of clustering:

```
cor <- cor (data)
dist<-dist(cor)
hclust<-hclust(dist)
plot(hclust)
```

And I will get a dendrogram after running the code above, while how can I draw a plot like this:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I follow what you want, then we need a function to compute WSS

```
wss <- function(d) {
  sum(scale(d, scale = FALSE)^2)
}
```

and a wrapper for this `wss()` function

```
wrap <- function(i, hc, x) {
  cl <- cutree(hc, i)
  spl <- split(x, cl)
  wss <- sum(sapply(spl, wss))
  wss
}
```

This wrapper takes the following arguments, inputs:

- `i` the number of clusters to cut the data into
- `hc` the hierarchical cluster analysis object
- `x` the original data

`wrap` then cuts the dendrogram into `i` clusters, splits the original data into the cluster membership given by `cl` and computes the WSS for each cluster. These WSS values are summed to give the WSS for that clustering.

We run all of this using `sapply` over the number of clusters 1, 2, ..., `nrow(data)`

```
res <- sapply(seq.int(1, nrow(data)), wrap, h = cl, x = data)
```

A screeplot can be drawn using

```
plot(seq_along(res), res, type = "b", pch = 19)
```

Here is an example using the well-known Edgar Anderson Iris data set:

```
iris2 <- iris[, 1:4]  # drop Species column
cl <- hclust(dist(iris2), method = "ward.D")

## Takes a little while as we evaluate all implied clustering up to 150 groups
res <- sapply(seq.int(1, nrow(iris2)), wrap, h = cl, x = iris2)
plot(seq_along(res), res, type = "b", pch = 19)
```

This gives:

[image]

We can zoom in by just showing the first 1:50 clusters

```
plot(seq_along(res[1:50]), res[1:50], type = "o", pch = 19)
```

which gives

[image]

You can speed up the main computation step by either running the `sapply()` via an appropriate parallelised alternative, or just do the computation for a fewer than `nrow(data)` clusters, e.g.

```
res <- sapply(seq.int(1, 50), wrap, h = cl, x = iris2) ## 1st 50 groups
```

Comment: Thank you! But why the values on y-axis are so huge, while the my data are very small indeed? In addition, can you answer my another question about wss-plot by the way?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25977798/why-is-the-line-of-wss-plot-for-optimize-the-cluster-analysis-looks-so-fluctua

Comment: The values on the y-axis are determined by the scale of the variables in your data. I'll take a look at the other Q.