# Working with sample data and getting error message

Tags: cluster-analysis, sample-data

I am trying to work with my data set to graph a cluster analysis similar to this example:

[Why is the line of wss-plot (for optimizing the cluster analysis) looks so fluctuated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25977798/why-is-the-line-of-wss-plot-for-optimizing-the-cluster-analysis-looks-so-fluct)

with a previous related thread ([How to draw the plot of within-cluster sum-of-squares for a cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959385/how-to-draw-the-plot-of-within-cluster-sum-of-squares-for-a-cluster#comment40678548_25960913))

When I follow along with the exact code of the thread (either the Iris example, or the person asking the question's example data) I get an error when attempting to plot the output: 
" Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :    (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double' "

The only thing I can think that is going wrong is perhaps the wrap function is not working properly. When I first attempted to do the code wrap was not recognized and so I installed the ggally package and then used the wrap function as presented in the sample codes.

Any help would be appreciated as I feel like there is some obvious and simple fix that I am missing.